# playing .wav file in tcl script

Tags: windows, tcl

Hello I'm trying to play a .wav file  in my tcl script but I'm unable to do so .,
I've tried installing package  Sound 1.0 but still its not working.I've pasted .wav file in c:/bin and tried `exec bell.wav` but o/p says

```
couldn't execute "TTBell.WAV": no such file or directory
```

Can I get help on this or any Windows API help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.WAV` files aren't executables, so you can't run them like that. The easiest way is through the `START` utility, like this:

```
set thefile "bell.wav"
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename [file normalize $thefile]]
```

If you're using older Tcl (8.4 or before) use this convoluted form instead:

```
set thefile "bell.wav"
eval exec [auto_execok start] [list "" [file nativename [file normalize $thefile]]]
```

In both cases, the empty argument (`""`) is *necessary* due to the weirdness of `START` in some cases…

Comment: thanks sir..This helped me instead of getting package or Win API.

Comment: I don't no why this question is getting down voted ... as I just wanted to know how to play .wav file in tcl script.